# What are the memory segments? File descriptors?

Tags: linux, unix, memory

1.What are the memory segments needed when executing a process? 
Is it connected to virtual memory?
2. What are the open file descriptors that exist in all Unix processes? 
thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunatly your question is too broad to be answered here, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Maybe you can edit your question and describe the practical problem you have ?

Comment: i am only looking for short answer, at least on how to start researching the questions.

Comment: These are operating system design questions, not programming questions.

Comment: <TLPI> is a very good book for you, if you are interested in linux programming, and want to learn it seriously, of cause it  answers your question very clearly, and countless other questions that you might want to ask, I am reading it, and it's better that I could expect.

Answer (score 1):

1. Memory Segments: Text, Data, BSS, Heap and Stack
2. File Descriptors: Standard Input (0), Standard Output (1) and Standard Error (2) and... they do not necessarily exists in ALL Unix processes (you can close them).